# SDK installation error

Tags: android

I recently installed android studio on my new PC. Since there was no SDK and IDE bundle anymore I downloaded the IDE alone. After doing so, it asked me to download the android SDK, but during download the download is always interrupted with a timeout error or an error that says "tag mismatch". So my question is, what could be the likely cause for this and what is the solution? If there's none, is there a place where I can download the files manually? Seems like the android studio page no longer shows the SDK.
**P.S** I have a working internet connection that I really don't have issues with.

Comment: did you have android studio or sdk before ??

Comment: No i did not have it. @SantanuSur

Comment: Locate the partially downloaded SDK, delete it. Restart your IDE, redownload.

Comment: @Taslim that wont be a solution because this happens everytime I redownload as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find websites that provide SDK manually. I'm not sure it is possible that is share a link here. But [This](https://dl2.soft98.ir/mobile/Android.SDK.Release.25.2.5.Win.rar?1518819711) is an instance. Download and extract and enter it's reference to Android studio.